# Sending user activity to database in json format

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I want to send user activity to database, where I defined a description column for it. I have to send it in `JSON` format.

I have several tables where users can add, edit or delete records.
So for example if a  user edits the table like this:

```
id: 1                               id:1
name: John                          name: Steve
mobile: 12345678                    mobile: 888999
email: john@doe.com                 email: steve@gmail.com
```

Then I want to send this activity to database like this:
`The "specific table" table was edited, name changed to "Steve", mobile changed to "888999", email changed to "steve@gmail.com"`

There are other columns for who made the changes and when. I never did something like this before, any suggestions or example which is the best way to start this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a tool like [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) for this purpose which gives you all information you want without any integration effort and almost no overhead.